# Optimal pixel drawing speed?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm using the Canvas object with javascript. Just doing some tests to see how fast I can set pixels in a draw loop.

On mac, it works great in FF, safari, chrome. On windows, I get a flickering effect on FF and  chrome. It looks like somehow the canvas implementation on windows is different than on mac for the different browsers? (not sure if that's true).

This is the basic code I'm using to do the drawing (taken from the article below - I've optimized the below to tighten the draw loop, it runs pretty smooth now):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvasElt');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var canvasData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
for (var x = 0; x < canvasData.width; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < canvasData.height; y++) {
        // Index of the pixel in the array
        var idx = (x + y * canvas.width) * 4;
        canvasData.data[idx + 0] = 0;
        canvasData.data[idx + 1] = 255;
        canvasData.data[idx + 2] = 0;
        canvasData.data[idx + 3] = 255;
    }
}
ctx.putImageData(canvasData, 0, 0);
```

again, browers on windows will flicker a bit. It looks like the canvas implementation is trying to clear the canvas to white before the next drawing operation takes place (this does not happen on mac). I'm wondering if there is a setting I can change in the Canvas object to modify that value (double-buffering, clear before draw, etc)?

This is the article I am using as reference:
http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/pushing-pixels-with-canvas/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the way the browsers use the native graphics APIs on the different OSes. And even on the same OS, using different APIs (for example GDI vs. Direct2D in Windows) would also produce different results.

Comment: Yeah I guess there's nothing to be done about it - there's no way to tell Canvas to change the way the browser implements redrawing, right? Like a canvas.pleaseDoubleBuffer="true" flag?

Comment: Or I mean rather - it just seems like the canvas on some implementations is erasing to white after each draw - if that could be turned off, all would be perfect. Don't think there's any such thing to do that though.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not aware of a way to control how the canvas uses the underlying OS APIs.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's fairly clear that browsers who implement the Canvas object use DIBS (device independent bitmaps). The fact that you have access to the pixelbuffer without having to lock the handle first is proof of this. And Direct2D has nothing to do with JS in a browser thats for sure. GDI is different since it uses DDBs (device dependent bitmaps, i.e allocated from video memory rather than conventional ram). All of this however has nothing to do with optimal JS rendering speed. I think writing the RGBA values as you do is probably the best way.

The crucial factor in the code above is the call to putImageData(). This is where browsers can differ in their implementation. Are you in fact writing directly to the DIB, and putImageData is simply a wrapper around InvalidateRect? Or are you in fact writing to a duplicate in memory, which in turn is copied into the canvas device context? If you use linux or mac then this is still a valid question. Although device contexts etc. are typically "windows" terms, most OS'es deal with handles or structures in pretty much the same way. But once again, we are at the mercy of the browser vendor.

I think the following can be said:

If you are drawing many pixels in one go, then writing directly to the pixelbuffer as you do is probably the best. It is faster to "bitblt" (copy) the pixelbuffer in one go after X number of operations. The reason for this is that the native graphics functions like FillRect also calls "invalidate rectangle" which tells the system that a portion if the screen needs a re-draw (refresh). So if you call 100 line commands, then 100 update's will be issued - slowing down the process. Unless (and this is the catch) you use the beginPath/EndPath methods as they should be used. Then it's a whole different ballgame.

It's here that the Begin/End path "system" comes into play, and also the Stroke/Outline commands. They allow you to execute X number of drawing operations within a single update. But a lot of people get this wrong and issue a redraw for each call to line/fillrect etc.

Also, have you tried creating an invisible canvas object, drawing to that, and then copying to a visible canvas? This could be faster (proper double-buffering).